# Get the name of file from file field before node is saved

Tags: files

There is a file upload field(which uploads zip files) . I want to get the name of file in `node_presave` , How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try some thing like

```
function module_node_presave($node)
{
   if($node->type=='article'){

       $file = file_load($node->field_zip['und'][0]['fid']);
       dpm($file->filename);
   }
}
```